# Is it possible to filter certain columns in GCP Cloud SQL replication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to filter certain columns in GCP Cloud SQL replication? eg: skip certain columns from replication

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate one of your MySQL instances, the replication will replicate all your data, so basically you can not specify certain columns to do the replication.

One thing that could be helpful for you, would be to separate your data into different MySQL instances.
In this way, you could put the data from the columns that you are interested in one single instance, and proceed with the replication.

Hope this helps!

Comment: *"basically you can not specify certain columns to do the replication"* is not strictly true of MySQL replication.  MySQL allows you to drop one or more columns from the "right side" of the table (the columns with the highest ordinal positions) on the replica, so as long as the rightmost columns are the ones you don't want to replicate, that's a supported configuration, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html.  Not sure if it's relevant to GC SQL.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was not clear, but I was talking about MySQL instances in GCP, so the limitation is in GCP, not in MySQL.